# Android implement Admob and subscription plans

Tags: android, admob, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I want to show ad's in my app and introduce subscription plans to the user.
I need to enable extra features and remove ad's for those who subscribe to the premium plan.
And if the subscription plan ends extra features need to be disabled and ad's should be shown.

How can I implement this in my app.

I can't find any proper resources to learn and implement these option's in my app.

Comment: In your you need to now about flavors in android where you can make a single application with two different version like one for normal user and one for premium user you can customize all the items according to flavors.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to now about flavors in android where you can make a single application with two different version like one for normal user and one for premium user you can customize all the items according to flavors.

1. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants
2. https://medium.com/@iammert/android-product-flavors-1ef276b2bbc1